# Trying to understand PostgreSQL Date/Time format

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I see date/time values like

```
2013-08-08 14:35:50-07
2014-02-20 01:57:59-08
```

Can someone please let me know what is that suffix 07 & 08 stand for?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Those](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) are [timezone offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). `2014-02-20 01:57:59-08` means 1:57 AM in [Pacific Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone)

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8601 offset for PST: 
See documentation:
(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)